# Why TreeModel's selection differs in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, groovy, spock, zk

I have implemented new model class for ZK Tree component.

```
public class AiTreeModel<E> extends DefaultTreeModel<E> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 20160122L;

    private void processChildNodes(TreeNode<E> node, boolean selected, IAttributeProcessor leafProcessor) {
        if (selected) {
            addToSelection(node);
        } else {
            removeFromSelection(node);
        }
        if (node.isLeaf()) {
            leafProcessor.process(node, selected);
        } else {
            node.getChildren().forEach(child -> processChildNodes(child, selected, leafProcessor));
        }
    }


    private boolean isSomeChildSelected(TreeNode<E> node) {
        if (node.isLeaf()) {
            return isSelected(node);
        } else {
            return node.getChildren().stream().anyMatch(this::isSomeChildSelected);
        }
    }

    private void checkParentNodes(final TreeNode<E> node, boolean selected) {
        TreeNode<E> parent = node.getParent();
        while (parent != null) {
            if (selected) {
                addToSelection(parent);
            } else {
                if (!isSomeChildSelected(parent)) {
                    removeFromSelection(parent);
                }
            }
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
    }

    public void processNode(TreeNode<E> node, boolean selected, IAttributeProcessor leafProcessor) {
        processChildNodes(node, selected, leafProcessor);
        checkParentNodes(node, selected);
    }

    public AiTreeModel(TreeNode<E> root) {
        super(root);
    }
}
```

In this model, there are few methods, which controls selection of parents.
Outside the class I use just one public method `processNode`.

I want to write simple Groovy JUnit test which will check this model. For example:

```
def "Test parent selection"() {
    setup:
    def AiTreeModel<?> model = new AiTreeModel<>(helper.getTreeByDate(new Date()));

    when:
    TreeNode<?> root = model.getRoot();
    def node = root.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0);
    model.processNode(node, true, this);

    then:
    model.getSelection().size() == 3
}
```

In runtime selection works correct and all parent nodes adds. But in the test, parent nodes rewrites in `Selection` map of model.

What I doing wrong?
Is this approach of testing correct?

Thanks for your answers and best regards.

Comment: That's a Spock test isn't it?

Comment: Why up passed `this` to `model.processNode(node, true, this)`. Could you please provide a full test source?

Comment: Yes, it's spock test.

Comment: I pass `this` in method call because method needs interface to handle leafs of tree while selecting/deselecting items.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was because the tree was in single selection mode.
`model.setMultiple(true);` and all works fine.

Thanks for wasting your time.